# can't display the label in full using Auto layout and stack views

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uistackview

[image: Stack view]

i have a stack view that has 3 buttons and 3 labels. The label's width is equal to the button's width so it's not showing it in full. How can i change the width of label so it can be displayed in full.

Answer (score 0):

You can change autolayout multiplier in autolayout settings to more greater value.
Choose your label in storyboard, in left bar you'll see autolayout settings. Choose width, it must be equal to button with multiplier's value 1. Change it to greater.

Also you can try to make font less.